# use of CompletableFuture.supplyAsync and CompletableFuture.completedFuture within @Async annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, future, completable-future

I have the following methods:

```
@EnableAsync
@Service
Class MyService{ 

private String processRequest() {
        log.info("Start processing request");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        log.info("Completed processing request");
        return RESULT;
    }    

@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> getSupplyAsyncResult(){
    CompletableFuture<String> future
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest);
    return future;
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> getCompletedFutureResult(){
    CompletableFuture<String> future
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest);
    return future;
}
```

and the following endpoints in controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/asyncSupplyAsync", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CompletableFuture<String> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {
        log.info("Request received");
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
                = myService.getSupplyAsyncResult();
        log.info("Servlet thread released");
        return completableFuture;
    }
```

and

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/asyncCompletable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CompletableFuture<String> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {
        log.info("Request received");
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
                = myService.getCompletedFutureResult();
        log.info("Servlet thread released");
        return completableFuture;
    }
```

Why would anyone use **completableFuture.supplyAsync** within @Async method in Spring endpoint?
I assume using **completableFuture.completedFuture**  is more appropriate, please share your views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They serve entirely different purposes to begin with. Before you think about how much it takes one or the other to process, you might want to understand how they work, first (so little calls are no indication of slow/fast anyway; these numbers mean nothing in this context).

Here is the same example you have:

```
public class SO64718973 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("dispatching to CF...");
        //CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processRequest());
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(processRequest());
        System.out.println("done dispatching to CF...");
        future.join();
    }

    private static String processRequest() {
        System.out.println("Start processing request");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Completed processing request");
        return "RESULT";
    }

}
```

You can run this and then change the implementation (by uncommenting `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`) and see where those `System.out.println` occur. You will notice that `completedFuture` will block `main` thread until it is executed, while `supplyAsync` will run in a different thread. So it's not like one is wrong and one is not, it depends on your use-case.

In general, it is not a great idea to use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` without configuring a pool for it; otherwise it will consume threads from `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: thanks for clarification, but if completedFuture() is executed by main thread (and not another thread in ForkJoinPool), then whats the need to basically use it since we can normally call our methods without even using completedFuture?

Comment: @MortezaN in _this_ case it is completed by main thread . There is nothing stopping you or anyone else  from sharing this `CompletableFuture` so that some other thread can complete it.

Comment: in the case of async spring, we have configured the executor. So does it mean that we should prefer ```supplyAsync```  in order to wrap blocking operation?